# Can't create new page

Tags: fitnesse-slim, fit-framework

I tried doing `url.NewPageName (http://localhost:3434/root.MyNewPage)`

I get `The requested resource: FrontPage.mynewpage was not found.`

I also tried the `[add child]` linkwhich gives a popup, and here I get `Invalid Child Name`.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://localhost:3434/MyNewPage

Comment: WOW. Same here. Name must have exactly 2 capital letters... :(

Comment: Actually, any even number of capital letters, with small letters in between :o)

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the **[add child]** link, be sure to enter it in Pascal case - like camel case but starting with a capital. For example: MyLocalTestPage